# How to get multiple nodes under 1 single node with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

My xml file looks something like this:

```
<PackageRuntimeContext xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UserToken>
<Id>449694</Id>
  </UserToken>
  <Addresses>
        <Address>
      <LastSeen xsi:nil="true" />
      <UniqueID>9afd29f6-f4fe-4a91-aade-da8a3fcdc358</UniqueID>
      <IsPrimary>true</IsPrimary>
      <Id>0</Id>
      <OrderID>0</OrderID>
      <SubjectId>0</SubjectId>
      <AddressLine1>123 Main St.</AddressLine1>
      <City>louisville</City>
      <State>KY</State>
      <ZipCode>40206</ZipCode>
    </Address>
    <Address>
      <LastSeen xsi:nil="true" />
      <UniqueID>0ae8014e-a950-48f3-8ee6-3526a7f3a50d</UniqueID>
      <IsPrimary>true</IsPrimary>
      <Id>0</Id>
      <OrderID>0</OrderID>
      <SubjectId>0</SubjectId>
      <AddressLine1>789 Elm St.</AddressLine1>
      <City>louisville</City>
      <State>KY</State>
      <ZipCode>40206</ZipCode>
    </Address>
    <Address>
      <LastSeen xsi:nil="true" />
      <UniqueID>b1bcc271-bec8-432f-b968-25430ba63b95</UniqueID>
      <IsPrimary>false</IsPrimary>
      <Id>0</Id>
      <OrderID>0</OrderID>
      <SubjectId>0</SubjectId>
      <AddressLine1>456 Oak St.</AddressLine1>
      <City>louisville</City>
      <State>KY</State>
      <ZipCode>40206</ZipCode>
    </Address>
  </Addresses>
```

I want to get the <**Id**> number 449694, and with it, the 3 (or whatever) subsequent <**UniqueID**> numbers under **Addresses/Address** so it looks something like this:

```
IDNumber      UniqueID
========      ========
449694         9afd29f6-f4fe-4a91-aade-da8a3fcdc358
449694         0ae8014e-a950-48f3-8ee6-3526a7f3a50d
449694         b1bcc271-bec8-432f-b968-25430ba63b95
```

The code If found here ([How to query values from xml nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712864/how-to-query-values-from-xml-nodes))  directed me to write something like this:

```
SELECT 
t.p.value('(./UserToken/Id)[1]', 'int') [IdNumber],
t.p.value('(./Addresses/Address/UniqueID)[1]', 'varchar(max)') [Context]
FROM product.PackageRuntimeState prs WITH(NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY prs.Context.nodes('/PackageRuntimeContext') t(p)
```

My results were:

```
IDNumber      UniqueID
========      ========
449694        9afd29f6-f4fe-4a91-aade-da8a3fcdc358
449694        b8439471-d4b9-46db-9321-b6175e1b8fb4  (this is from ANOTHER record)
449694        b8439471-d4b9-46db-9321-b6175e1b8fb4  (this too is from another record)
```

What do I need to do to my code to get the subsequent UniqueID nodes from my xml file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop down one more level.  You need to list the direct decendants of `<Addresses>`, not `<PackageRuntimeContext>`

```
SELECT
  t.p.value('(../../UserToken/Id)[1]', 'int') [IdNumber],
  t.p.value('(./UniqueID)[1]', 'varchar(max)') [Context]
FROM product.PackageRuntimeState prs WITH(NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY prs.Context.nodes('/PackageRuntimeContext/Addresses/Address') t(p)
```

Comment: When I try running the code as suggested I get "NULL" now in my "Context" field.  Probably because the full path to get to the UniqueID node is "PackageRuntimeContext/Addresses/Address/UniqueID" and the element "Address" is not being applied.  I tried

    t.p.value('(./Address/UniqueID)[1]', 'varchar(max') Context

and that got me back to my original results