# SQL Server : read XML data

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have this query taken from the site `www.SQLauthority.com`:

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<SampleXML>
<Colors>
<Color1>White</Color1>
<Color2>Blue</Color2>
<Color3>Black</Color3>
<Color4 Special="Light">Green</Color4>
<Color5>Red</Color5>
</Colors>
<Fruits>
<Fruits1>Apple</Fruits1>
<Fruits2>Pineapple</Fruits2>
<Fruits3>Grapes</Fruits3>
<Fruits4>Melon</Fruits4>
</Fruits>
</SampleXML>'

SELECT
    a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color1[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color1,
    a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color2[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color2,
    a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color3[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color3,
    a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color4[1]/@Special','varchar(10)')+' '+
    +a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color4[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color4,
    a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color5[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color5,
    a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits1[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits1,
    a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits2[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits2,
    a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits3[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits3,
    a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits4[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits4
FROM @MyXML.nodes('SampleXML') a(b)
```

I am not getting a better picture of how the nodes fetching from the xml data.

I have few queries regarding this.

1. what is `a(b)` in this?
2. how the structure will change if i have another node inside colors and all the existing child nodes appended to that?

ie:

```
 <Colorss>
   <Colors>
      <Color1>White</Color1>
      <Color2>Blue</Color2>
      <Color3>Black</Color3>
      <Color4 Special="Light">Green</Color4>
      <Color5>Red</Color5>
   </Colors>
<Colorss>
<Fruits>
     <Fruits1>Apple</Fruits1>
     <Fruits2>Pineapple</Fruits2>
     <Fruits3>Grapes</Fruits3>
     <Fruits4>Melon</Fruits4>
</Fruits>
```

3. what does it mean by `a.b.value`? When I mouse over it shows a is derived table. Can I check value of the table a?

Any help in this will be appreciated.

Comment: Your first question is answered in part in the comments of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14713431/772086). Also, take a look at the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is a(b) in this?

The call to `.nodes('SampleXML')` is a XQuery function which returns a pseudo table which contains one column of an XML fragment for each of the elements that this XPath expression matches - and the `a(b)` is the table alias (`a`) for that column, and `b` is the name of the column in that pseudo table containing the XML fragments.

> what does it mean by `a.b.value`?

This is based on the above - `a` is the **table alias** for that temporary, inline pseudo table, `b` is the **column name** for the column in that table, and `.value()` is another XQuery function that will extract a single value from XML, based on the XPath expression (first argument) and it will return it as the datatype specified in the second argument.

You should check out those introductions to XQuery support in SQL Server to understand better:

- [Introduction to XQuery in SQL Server 2005](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- [XQuery basics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/608459/XQuery-basics)

and there are numerous other introductions and tutorials on XQuery - just search with your favorite search engine and you'll get tons of hits!

Answer (score 1):

here's my stab @ it:

1. a-refers to root;b-refers to root and child node

> ```
>     DECLARE @MyXML XML
> SET @MyXML = '<SampleXML>
> <Colors>
> <Color1>White</Color1>
> <Color2>Blue</Color2>
> <Color3>Black</Color3>
> <Color4 Special="Light">Green</Color4>
> <Color5>Red
>   <Color6>Black44</Color6>
>   <Color7>Black445</Color7>
> </Color5>
> </Colors>
> <Fruits>
> <Fruits1>Apple</Fruits1>
> <Fruits2>Pineapple</Fruits2>
> <Fruits3>Grapes</Fruits3>
> <Fruits4>Melon</Fruits4>
> </Fruits>
> </SampleXML>'
> ```

2. to get an inner child

   SELECT
   a.c.value('Colors[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Color1[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)','varchar(10)') AS Color1,
   a.c.value('Colors[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Color2[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)','varchar(10)') AS Color2,
   a.c.value('Colors[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Color3[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)','varchar(10)') AS Color3,
   a.c.value('Colors[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Color4[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/@Special','varchar(10)') AS Color4,
   a.c.value('Colors[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Color5[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)','varchar(10)') AS Color5,
    a.c.value('Colors[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Color5[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Color7[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)','varchar(50)') AS Color6a,
      a.c.value('Colors[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Color5[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Color6[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)','varchar(50)') AS Color6b,    a.c.value('Fruits[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Fruits1[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)','varchar(10)') AS Fruits1,
   a.c.value('Fruits[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Fruits2[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)','varchar(10)') AS Fruits2,
   a.c.value('Fruits[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Fruits3[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)','varchar(10)') AS Fruits3,
   a.c.value('Fruits[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)/Fruits4[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)','varchar(10)') AS Fruits4
    FROM @MyXML.nodes('SampleXML') a(c)
3. A nodes() method invocation with the query expression /root/Color(n) would return a rowset with three rows, each containing a logical copy of the original XML document, and with the context item set to one of the  nodes
   [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: i couldnt understand the point 2. How that value attained? i edited my question for a better picture of my doubt. If i need to fetch a value of color1 from samplexml/colorss/colors/color1 how the code will change?