# How to search the XML node values stored in table column in SQL Server

Tags: xml, t-sql, azure-sql-database, xquery

I was referring to this : [How to query values from xml nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712864/how-to-query-values-from-xml-nodes)
and tried to find the best and quick way to search the node values, if exists, but somehow it looks completed explanation than that I was originally thinking.

There are around 10K records in the DB table. One of the column stores the XML in the table, the  column value is just similar to this ( with lot many other nodes):

```html
<GrobReportXmlFileXmlFile>
   <GrobReport>
       <ReportHeader>
          <OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>Hello</OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>
          <OrganizationNumber>Hi</OrganizationNumber>
       </ReportHeader>
  </GrobReport>
   <GrobReport>
       <ReportHeader>
          <OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>Find</OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>
          <OrganizationNumber>Me</OrganizationNumber>
       </ReportHeader>
  </GrobReport>
```

The script I have tried is:

```
 select columnname.value('(GrobReportXmlFileXmlFile/GrobReport/ReportHeader/OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier/)[Hello]',nvarchar(max)) from Table
```

Note: My columnname is:

> columnname(nvarchar(max),null)

However, its showing error, nvarchar is not recognized by build-in function.

I have changed my query like this:

```
 select T.[columnname].value('(GrobReportXmlFileXmlFile/GrobReport/ReportHeader/OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier/)[Hello]','nvarchar(max)') from Table as T
```

However, in this case I'm getting error as:

> Can not call method on nvarchar(max)

Any idea, if .value needs to be replaced by some other function as its type is nvarchar(max)? Is there any alternative for "value" function, that I can try?

I would like to find if any particular value (lets say "Hello") exist in any of the column/node or not?If it exists then it should return me the number of records(rows) in which the searched value present?

Thanks

Comment: What is "nvarchar(max)" supposed to be?  What is "max"?  Does not look like correct syntax

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. The column data type is defined like this. The DB is Azure SQL DB and I'm using SSMS 2019 to write/execute the query.

Comment: Is nvarchar(MAX) supposed to be in single quotes: 'nvarchar(max)'?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Yes, I changed that. However, now I'm getting a new error: Can not find either column 'columnname' or user-defined function or aggregate "columnname.value", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: columnname should be the name of the physical column on your table: select [name_of_col_here].value

Comment: yes. That is correct and I did exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following three methods:

1. CTE and rectangular/relational data set with `WHERE` clause.
2. XPath predicate.
3. `.exist()` method.

Method #1. A combination of `.nodes()` and `.value()` methods convert XML into a rectangular data sets inside the CTE. After that a WHERE clause finds what is needed based on the search criteria.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata)
VALUES
(N'<GrobReportXmlFileXmlFile>
    <GrobReport>
        <ReportHeader>
            <OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>Hello</OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>
            <OrganizationNumber>Hi</OrganizationNumber>
        </ReportHeader>
    </GrobReport>
    <GrobReport>
        <ReportHeader>
            <OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>Find</OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>
            <OrganizationNumber>Me</OrganizationNumber>
        </ReportHeader>
    </GrobReport>
</GrobReportXmlFileXmlFile>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @searchParam VARCHAR(20) = 'Hello';

-- Method #1
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ID, TRY_CAST(xmldata AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
), rs AS
(
SELECT ID 
    , c.value('(OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier
    , c.value('(OrganizationNumber/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS OrganizationNumber
FROM cte AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('/GrobReportXmlFileXmlFile/GrobReport/ReportHeader') AS t(c)
)
SELECT * FROM  rs
-- apply any filter(s) here
WHERE OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier = @searchParam;
```

> Output

```
+----+---------------------------------------+--------------------+
| ID | OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier | OrganizationNumber |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | Hello                                 | Hi                 |
|  1 | Find                                  | Me                 |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Method #2, based on the XPath predicate

```
-- Method #2
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ID, TRY_CAST(xmldata AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID 
    , c.value('(OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier
    , c.value('(OrganizationNumber/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS OrganizationNumber
FROM cte AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('/GrobReportXmlFileXmlFile/GrobReport/ReportHeader[(OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier/text())[1] eq sql:variable("@searchParam")]') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+----+---------------------------------------+--------------------+
| ID | OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier | OrganizationNumber |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | Hello                                 | Hi                 |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Method #3, based on the `.exist()` method.

```
-- Method #3
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ID, TRY_CAST(xmldata AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID 
    , c.value('(OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier
    , c.value('(OrganizationNumber/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS OrganizationNumber
FROM cte AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('/GrobReportXmlFileXmlFile/GrobReport/ReportHeader') AS t(c)
WHERE c.exist('OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier[. eq sql:variable("@searchParam")]') = 1;
```

Comment: Good answer, plused it :-)

Comment: Thanks. However, my column type is not XML and I can't change that. I'm getting error: The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on column of type XML. Any other solution for this please?

Comment: @AskMe, That's why it is so important to provide a DDL and sample data population while asking a question. I modified column data type from `XML` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and updated the answer.